# How to get a keycode from my mouse's side button?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, xmodmap

In my .bashrc, I would like to add this line :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Return"
```

where the keycode number is the one from my mouse's side button.

To find a keycode from the keyboard, I use xev, which gives me, for instance:

(the line that contains "keycode 135" is the one that matters)

```
 KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,    
     root 0x7c3, subw 0x0, time 30530179, (-489,479), root:(1047,479),    
     state 0x0, keycode 135 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,    
     XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 36 "   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) " "   XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "    
     XFilterEvent returns: False
```

However, for a mouse, it doesn't show the keycode:

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x7c3, subw 0x0, time 30661669, (35,100), root:(1571,100),
    state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES
```

How to get a keycode from my mouse's side button, to use the command xmodmap, to simulate a keyboard's key press from a mouse button? (for instance, pressing the side button would be as if I would press "a" on keyboard - and would show "a" in a text editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t, at least not with only `xmodmap` — mice and keyboards are handled differently, and mice don’t produce keycodes.

There are however tools which can remap input events across different device types; try [Key Mapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper/) for example. (I’m a very minor contributor to the project.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming there is no keycode for mice. I haven't tried key mapper yet though